# How to programmatically add a new logger and appender to existing XML configuration

Tags: logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 v2.11. I have a simple log4j2.xml file. I need to perform default logging with the loggers loaded from this file. However, depending upon the process spawned, i need to create a different log file with the name of the process along with the xml loaded configuration.

I am aware of :-

```
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(...);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(...);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(...);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, Level.DEBUG, null);
    config.addLogger("myapp.namespace", loggerConfig);
    ctx.updateLoggers();
```

However, createAppender and createLogger are deprecated methods in V2.11.

Besides, I am also aware of ConfigurationBuilder. I have tried it out and it seems it is for programmatically building the Configuration. I need to have the default configuration to come form log4j2.xml file. And append the new appender (with new file name and logger).

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of `log4j2`, `Appender` instance can be created by using its `Builder`. So, for creating `FileAppender` instance, you can write something like below -

```
Appender fileAppender = FileAppender.newBuilder().setName("fileAppender")
                .withFileName(basePath + "dynamic_logs.log").setLayout(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN)
                .build();
```

And for creating logger, `LoggerConfig` class static methods are used. There are 2 methods for creating logger in `LoggerConfig` class. Only one method that accepts first argument `additivity` as String value has been deprecated. Another method that accepts first argument as boolean type is used now.

One way of creating dynamic Logger is mentioned below -

```
LoggerConfig dynamicLogger = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.INFO, "logger.name", null, refs, null, config, null);
```

Comment: I'm beginning to hate builders, even if they're probably for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vikas. Sorry for the late response.
Before i received your response i resolved my issue in a different way. As you might have guessed i needed to specify the name of the log file at runtime.

I used the 
fileName="${sys:logpath.name}" 
configuration and set its value System.setProperty("logpath.name","logs/.log");